# .bat file works on two domain systems but not other systems

Tags: batch-file, taskkill

The .bat file is located in C:\Temp in a domain network. It will be ran via shortcut on user desktop. Using this setup, on my system and on one other system (laptop Win 7 Pro and Desktop Win 7 Pro), it works. Different users. I have admin account, and test profile call joe user (juser) no admin rights. Does what it is intended to do. Tried on additional users desktops under their profile and it fails. Does not find the files. I added pauses after each command to decipher and found the errors. Verified files are indeed there. Able to browse to location and actually see the files.

Can someone help point out what I am not seeing?

Again it works on my system, a default user with no admin rights systems for testing purposes, but fails on others.

```
@echo off
title This will delete you cookies!

echo This will program will close all Chrome Windows and clear cookies. Make sure all data is saved before pressing any key.
pause

echo Are you sure you are ready?
pause

echo Absolutely sure?
pause

taskkill /IM Chrome.exe /F
cd %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\
del Cookies
del Cookies-journal
del Current Session
```

Comment: try with  `cd "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\"` . Could be something with the spaces.

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: The " " did the trick and allow the script to work on the system. 

To answer your question though, it did prompt with unable to find file message on non working systems.

No I am set to working on clearing all the cookies. While the files was deleted, do to force closing the process, it leaves the open webpages due to Chrome being improperly closed. But something I can work on myself.

Thank you for pointing out the " "s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

…perhaps:

```bat
TaskKill /F /IM Chrome.exe /T 2>Nul
CD/D "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"
Del/A/F Cookies Cookies-journal "Current Session"
```

Comment: Del/A/F Cookies Cookies-journal "Current Session" "Current Tabs"

Attempted this script as well, and found adding "Current Tabs" to the above suggestion does the complete job of clearing all.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `cookies`, `cookies-journal` etc. are directories, you need `rd /s /q "cookies"` etc.

`rd` removes a directory, `/s` means "and subdirectories" `/q` "quietly" and the quotes need to surround the target directory-name where the directory-name "contains spaces" (and are harmless otherwise)

Comment: they are files on my machine/

Comment: They are not directories but plain files. Attempting to remove Chrome Cookie files to automate cookie removal for users.

Comment: Could say I'm rusty on chrome, but I never use it... OK, should be `del` then. Agree with @npocmaka - any error messages?

Comment: The " " did the trick and allow the script to work on the system. To answer your question though, it did prompt with unable to find file message on non working systems. No I am set to working on clearing all the cookies. While the files was deleted, do to force closing the process, it leaves the open webpages due to Chrome being improperly closed. But something I can work on myself.